# Changing CKEDITOR value removes event listener

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a page with several CKEDITOR fields, where I catch a click event.
When clicking a certain button, the field is cleared, which unfortunately also removes the event listener.

This seems to be a known issue.
I have tried solutions provided elsewhere, but I'm still stuck.

code:

```
var aInst = CKEDITOR.instances;
for (var key in aInst){
    CKEDITOR.instances[key].on('contentDom', function() {
        console.log('initial or change');
        this.editable().attachListener(this.document,'click', function(){
            console.log('iframe click');
        });
    });
}
```

clicking in the initial, unchanged field will get me the 'iframe click' log.

when

```
CKEDITOR.instances[cpdId+'_flip_text_input'].setData('');
```

is activated, I get the 'initial or change' log, but clicking in the field isn't caught anymore.

This is already a version changed to a solution elsewhere (not working for me), because originally `this.editable().attachListener(this.document,'click', function(){` was simply `this.document.on('click', function(){`

CKEDITOR v4.6.2

JQuery v3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a hacky way. First of all, I replaced

```
CKEDITOR.instances[key].on('contentDom', function() {
```

with

```
CKEDITOR.instances[key].on('instanceReady', function() {
```

so the original attaching of the listener happens only on loading the page.

I removed

```
CKEDITOR.instances[cpdId+'_flip_text_input'].setData('');
```

completely and replaced with my 'hacky' solution: I removed everything inside the wrapper around the editor and textarea, refilled it with the 'original' code, re-activated the ckeditor on it and then attached the listener, works like a charm:

```
(var reFill = original html with textarea)

$('#'+cpdId+'_flip_text').empty();
$('#'+cpdId+'_flip_text').html(reFill);
$('#'+cpdId+'_flip_text').find('textarea').ckeditor(function(){
    var CKedit = CKEDITOR.instances[cpdId+'_flip_text_input'];
    CKedit.editable().attachListener(CKedit.document,'click', function(){
        //stuff to do on click
    });
});
```